# Increment variable on every call of method

Tags: c++, loops, variables, increment

I have this method :

```
void Session::onNewImage(cv::Mat& img, double elapsedTime){
    static int count = 0;
    add(img, dnnOutput[count++], curLati, curLongi, curAlti, curHeading, curRoll);
}
```

It's been called 1400 times. Each time the value of "count" is incremented. But when it comes at 1401 time, I want "count" to become 0 , and then again increment form there. I don't want "count" to be a global variable. How can i achieve this ?

P.S.  I cannot hard code it as 1400. It can be different everytime. There is another method which decides how many times this method will be called, Depending on number of images given as input to that method.

Comment: `if ( count > 1400 ) count = 0;`?

Comment: Use the % (modulus) operator.

Comment: That value, 1400, is the size of dnnOutput? Is that an array or a vector?

Comment: Sorry to give "one of those" comments, but perhaps you would be better off explaining what it is you are trying to achieve. The actual solution you seek is probably not in the details of this particular function but in the overall design of your implementation. You obviously have some state on your class which you are accessing in this method, and you make assumptions about that state; how is that state different from your `count` variable?

Comment: Catching up on @odyss-jii and previous comments: assuming maximum count is sizeof dnnOutput, which might be a `std::vector<...>`, then you could do e. g. `count = (count + 1) % dnnOutput.size();`. Fine so far. But if you restart at 0, have you assured that whatever processing is to be done on the image is *completed* before you re-use it? Or at least, that there are no conflicts if `newImage(0)` and `newImage(1400)` reuse the same data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
void Session::onNewImage(cv::Mat& img, double elapsedTime){
    static int count = 0;

    if (count >= getYourCountLimitFromSomewhere())
        count = 0;

    add(img, dnnOutput[count++], curLati, curLongi, curAlti, curHeading, curRoll);
}
```

Note that as @Aconcagua has pointed out in the comments, whether the comparison of `count` with the threshold is via `>` or `>=` depends on the meaning of the `getYourCountLimitFromSomewhere()` return value.

Comment: Actually, I like this better than my modulus suggestion, I think it's clearer. I was just being lazy.

Comment: When I saw the `%` suggestion, I found it better than this plain approach :) You're probably right about the readability aspect, though.

Comment: Well I forgot to mention. I cannot hard code it as 1400. It can be different everytime.

Comment: But how is the max. number of calls specified, then?

Comment: the line `static int count = 0;` ; shouldn't it be out of the method?

Comment: There is another method which decides how many times this method will be called, Depending on number of images given as input to that method.

Comment: One issue left: Question says "loop shall run 1400 times, 1401th run shall restart with 0" - assuming counting the loop runs is 1-based, we would have to compare `if(count >= 1400)`, not `>` as was before. Accordingly, if the limit function returns size (in case of array/vector), not maximum value, we'd have to compare with `>=` here as well. OK, open what the function actually returns, but we have to keep this in mind...